# Graphviz dot language - drawing a single disconnected node/vertex?

Tags: graphviz

I've been Googling for this for quite a while and yet I couldn't find anything. How do I draw a graph with Graphviz that has no vertices connected to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
digraph g {
  SingleNode;
}
```

Simply do **not** define any edges connecting the node to other nodes (`SingleNode -> OtherNode`).